# Phaser framework, this vs var

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm having trouble understanding var vs this. I realise 'this' refers to the methods object.

However, in the example below, can any clarify why we are using 'var box' instead of this.box?. On the other hand, we are using this.spinner?

```
var MyGame = {};
MyGame.StateA = function (game) {
this.spinner = null; this.text = null;
};

MyGame.StateA.prototype = {

init: function () {
var box = this.make.graphics(0, 0);
box.lineStyle(8, 0xFF0000, 0.8); 
box.beginFill(0xFF700B, 1); 
box.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100); 
box.endFill();

this.spinner = this.add.sprite( this.world.centerX, this.world.centerY,     box.generateTexture() );
```

Answer (score 1):

> why we are using 'var box' instead of this.box?

In JavaScript, objects are assigned to a variable *by reference*. 
After assigning `this.make.graphics` to `box`, it is just easier to manipulate.

In terms of functionality `box.lineStyle(8, 0xFF0000, 0.8);` and `this.make.graphics.lineStyle(8, 0xFF0000, 0.8);` would do the same.
But `box.lineStyle` is shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var box = this.make.graphics(0, 0);
```

Here is variable definition, by word "var" in javascript we define/declare variables. By "this" we are using in "function" scopes, and it refers to the object and his scope. If you will use

```
this.box = this.make.graphics(0, 0);
```

Then probalby it will ascribe it to window global variable. This everything depends on scope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

This is a difference between var and this. Is using in totally diferent cases.